# How to surround some html code in Eclipse with new tag (shortcut)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I want to surround some HTML code with `<div>` - how to do it in Eclipse with some shortcuts or macros. I do not want to repeat surrounding manually.

```
<p>some text</p>
```

I want to surround with `<div>` and achieve

```
<div><p>some text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow below mentioned steps :

1. Select the text that you want to surround with tag.
2. Go to 'Edit > Quick Fix' or press 'Ctrl + 1'.
3. Double click "Surround with new element"

Comment: Partially working but only on pure html. Html + djanog fails since unknown tags. Another problem Ctrl+1 is reformatting code - code looks more ugly than nice.